# Theme path in javascript

Tags: theming, 8, javascript

I need to use my theme path in a jQuery script for a D8 theme I'm building. I know this is available as drupalSettings.path.baseURL (followed by the path to my theme) but how do you make this variable available to javascript? Lots of D7 info out there, not much D8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can attach the drupalSettings in any form / build / preprocess etc.

Something like :

```
function HOOK_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
 $variables['#attached']['drupalSettings']['path']['themeUrl'] = \Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme()->getPath();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dylan! It turns out the solution requires doing both what you show here, and 4k4's solution below.

Answer (score 4):

To make the variables from drupalSettings available in custom javascript code, you have to add `core/drupalSettings` as dependency when you define the library:

**mytheme.libraries.yml**

```
custom-javascript:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/custom-javascript.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupalSettings
```

**mytheme.info.yml**:

```
libraries:
  - mytheme/custom-javascript
```

**js/custom-javascript.js**

```
(function ($, drupalSettings) {

  var baseURL = drupalSettings.path.baseURL;

})(jQuery, drupalSettings);
```

Comment: Thanks! Turns out the solution requires both this answer and the one from Dylan above.